# Custom ASP.NET MVC Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I think I'm having a stupid moment. I am currently looking into ASP.NET MVC authorization and cannot figure it out :(

I have seem a large number of tutorials explaining on how we can use the [Authorize] attribute to restrict Controllers & Actions to only the authorized users. What all of these tutorials seem to be missing (or otherwise I am losing my mind) is:

- What happens if a user is not authenticated? None of these tutorials seem to handle this scenario - they just allow users to see the default Unauthorized error page. How do we get the Authorize attribute redirecting to a login page in this case?
- How do we add users to be authorized? I have a custom DB with custom users & do not want to use the default ASP.NET MVC DB that comes with sample project with Authorization enabled. How do we get the Authorize attribute playing ball with custom DBs?

The only way out I can see right now is extending and overriding the Authorize attribute to provide custom handling for basic authorization & login mechanisms.

Am I missing something completely obvious?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: If your web.config file has `<system.web><authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="10" />` (the default setup) then you will automatically be redirected to the Login page if you are not authorized

Comment: I think the obvious thing is indeed to override the Authorize attribute to add your custom logic.